# OpenCV(python) Поиск положения контура в пространстве, перспективные преобразования

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Столкнулся с задачей поиска положения объекта в пространстве. На вход получаю фотографию с камеры , которая может находиться как параллельно плоскости , на которой расположены объекты , так и под углом к ней. Идея поиска в том, что на фотографии есть 4 интересующих меня контура:начало отсчета, и ограничители по осям Х и Y, ограничители это два квадратных и один круглый контур, и относительно этих контуров нужно найти расположение четвертого, так же круглого и вывести его координату. На изображении так же присутствуют и другие(побочные) контура. На данный момент я смог реализовать преобразование изображение методом Canny и получение всех контуров изображения. Вопрос далее только в том, как определить расположение нужного мне контура относительно трех других, если камера может стоять в различных позициях под разными углами? Я подумал про перспективные преобразования, которые позволяют от изображения под углом получить изображение плоское, т.е. как будто камера смотрит сверху(параллельно плоскости на которой расположены предметы) и тогда мне будет просто достаточно определить нужные мне контура, так как они являются квадратами и окружностями. Но насколько мне известно, для этого метода нужно знать как минимум координаты трёх точек на исходном изображении и их же на преобразованном. По идее я этих координат не знаю, так как угол под которым находится камера - варьируется. У меня ещё была идея пойти через поиск площади, так как в принципе она не меняется в зависимости от положения камеры, но мне кажется, что этот метод не очень эффективен в моем случае. Подскажите возможные варианты действий , быть может есть еще варианты помимо перспективных преобразований и поиска площади/длины, буду очень благодарен!